# How to display multiple row values in musql table in a single html table row

Tags: php, mysql

I have database table like this

```
Treatment_ID       Drugname
 1                 panadol
 1                 piriton
 1                 Parasitamo
```

I want to display this information in a html table as follows

```
 treatmentid          drugname
    1                panadol,piriton,Parasitamo
```

How I can display as above html table?

Comment: [`GROUP_CONCAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat), be very aware of `group_concat_max_len`.

Comment: You can get your results from the DB then just concat them in the scripting language of your preference. Every lang has something of this sort. PHP has `implode(', ', $result)` javascript has `results.join(',')` and so on. I don't think there's a way to get the result you want straight from the database.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. you can have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/tour, just to know how to accept answer and so on. @user3933325

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using group_concat like this

```
SELECT Treatment_ID as treatmentid, group_concat(Drugname SEPARATOR ',' ) AS drugname
FROM tablename GROUP BY Treatment_ID
```